# Which users are considered as pro-tem moderator?

Tags: support

I understand that [Constable](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/badges/111/constable) badge will be awarded to users who Served as a **pro-tem moderator** for at least 1 year or through site graduation.

I didn't understand, what does `pro-tem` moderator means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Moderator Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) article on official blog:

> ## How Moderators are Appointed Pro Tem
>
> About a week into the public beta, we will seek out members who are deeply engaged in the community’s development; members who:
>
> - Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
> - Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
> - Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
> - Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in A Theory of Moderation.
>
> Bonus points for:
>
> - Members with participation in both meta and the parent site (i.e. interest in both community building and expertise in the field).
> - Area 51 participation, social network referrals, or blogging about the site.
> - Members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.

Answer (score 3):

*Pro-temp moderators* or *pro-tempore moderators* are those moderators appointed by Stack Exchange when the site is still in beta phase, before elections. Once elections are open, pro-temp moderators stop to exist, and new elected moderators take their place. It could happen pro-temp moderators are elected, but it is not necessary the case.